# How to configure one-to-one relations to the same table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have a model as follows:

```
 public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Parent property is related to the same table. How can i configure it?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
         .HasOne(a => a.Parent)
         .OnDelete(false);
        }
```

I'm newbie with Entity framework core, please help me !!!

Comment: Please help me !!!

Comment: on top on top on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resoled by:

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId{ get; set; } /*added*/
        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]   /*added*/
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```